# PHP serverside includes

Tags: php, include

I have a PHP file with following contents:

```
<?php
$myflash  = $_GET["flashname"];
$mytitl   = $_GET["titlname"];
$myqgif   = $_GET["flashgif"];
$mytxt    = $_GET["txtname"];
?>

<?php
include('01.txt');
?>
```

It displays properly. But when I use the following:

```
<?php
include('<?php echo $mytxt; ?>.txt');
?>
```

It doesn't display.

Comment: Just to be sure, that line with `?php` was meant to be `<?php`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
?php
include('<?php echo $mytxt; ?>.txt');
?>
```

is not valid PHP syntax... code inside `<?php ?>` is already PHP code. you don't put more php tags in it.

You want to use just:

```
<?php
    include($mytxt . '.txt');
?>
```

You have the php tags for PHP code and then one include statement. Inside that statement, you concatenate two strings (`$mytxt` and `.txt`) to form a file name to include.

PLEASE make sure to sanitize your input before including it. Someone could easily change the GET parameter and your script would `include` any file they wanted. Make sure the file is where you want it to be before including.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do an echo inside of a string. Instead, you're looking for string concatenation:

```
include( $mytxt . '.txt');
```

Note that you will have to sanitize `$mytxt` to avoid [Local File Inclusion](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Local_File_Inclusion) (LFI) vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include('<?php echo $mytxt; ?>.txt');
?>
```

Is already PHP. You don't need to re-open your php tags.

```
<?php
include($mytxt . ".txt");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not diplay anything becuase the [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function is taking the argument as a **filename** and path, not PHP code.

If you put `echo $mytxt;` into `foobar.php` and say `include('foobar.php');` it will work. But it's pointless in its current form.

The `01.txt` is being displayed because the contents of it (`01.txt` is a file) are loaded into the code. Mainly because it's not a PHP code, it will be dumped to the browser. Include should be used to get other PHP scripts to be executed in our code.